# Looking for software that would enable me to cast a screen over LAN

Tags: classroom-infrastructure

I'm working at the university in a computer lab and I'm looking for a Microsoft Windows software, that would enable me to cast a screen of my computer (master) to all other student's computers which are in the same local network.

I have already found several different solutions, but **none of them enables me to force the slave computers to start the screen casting software**.

The idea here is, when I'm showing something on my computer I would start the screen casting software on all slave computers, and students won't be able to close this window until i'm done.
Does software like this exist?

Comment: FYI we have a sister site for [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I'm not sure which site would be best able to answer this question. Please don't post the same question there, but do have a look to see whether someone has asked a similar one and got an answer. If you think the other site would have been a better place to ask, you can click the "flag" link and request that the moderators migrate it.

Comment: Have you considered a projector?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to CSEd.

Comment: @Keelan I don't think that not being specific is a good reason to close. It is certainly valid for questions to be acceptable on multiple sites. To general or 'opinion based' - but I don't see any answers which are specificly addressing the 'control' aspect explicitly.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane my answer addresses the control aspect.

Comment: Use https://go.twitch.tv/ if you want to look cool ;) (This isn't used for educational purposes but by gamers, and eventually programmers who would share their screen while they slay some monsters or code a program).

Answer (score 1):

I know of two bits of software that can do what you want.

They do what you are looking for, display stuff on their screen and do demonstrations on their screen. They also lets you spy on your pupils, blank screens, lock screens (useful if they are not paying attention), and shutdown computers at end of day.

## AB Tutor

I have used this software, in the schools I have worked in.
On the negative side it is proprietary, and expensive.

## Veyon

I have not used it. But it is Free Software and cheep.
See http://veyon.io/

Answer (score 1):

We've used [Impero](https://www.imperosoftware.com/uk/) in our labs quite successfully.  It allowed me to broadcast my screen to 30 others as well as quickly jump in and take control of other screens if a student was stuck.  It is paid and we've used it throughout the school, not just for CS.  Network managers use it for quickly trouble-shooting pupil machines for instance.

Comment: Welcome. Can you add any more detail to your answer? For example, is it paid, does your school use it universally, or just for CS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

Use [open broadcast system](https://obsproject.com/) and you can [stream over lan](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/streaming-over-lan-with-local-rtmp-server.2427/) quite easily.

You can use [OBS configs and set up ffmpeg to broadcast over multicast address](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-studio-send-an-udp-stream-to-a-second-pc-using-obs.455/). Or set up [nginx as an RTMP server](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/)

## Notes and thoughts

### Why OBS?

First and foremost, I use it and I love it :-)

It's a completely free, and fully open source software that deploys very quickly.

Open broadcast system is a powerful multi-platform (windows, linux, macosx) application that's super easy to configure and get going. There are tons of tutorials and it's well developed and well documented.

It comes with built-in config's for most streaming environments e.g. YouTube, liveedu.tv, etc.

You can simultaneously stream and locally record your videos at different resolutions and framerates simultaneously, and has support for multiple screens, desktops, capturing individual windows and a whole host of other capabilities.

The audio/video/desktop-capture capabilities are more than impressive.

## Using NGINX for RTMP

nginx RTMP configuration takes about 10 minutes of reading and about 5 minutes to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Our district has Adobe Connect. It's used mostly for remote training, but any of us have access to setup classes. I use it pretty much any time I demo.

I also project my screen. Most watch on their screens while they're typing, but some like to look at the projector screen.